# I'm looking for an email provider like this

Tags: privacy, email, account-security, tor

I am looking for email providers with the following conditions for privacy.

email providers that:

- Are free.
- Do not require JavaScript or other credentials for registration.
- Provide an onion service.
- Support PGP encryption and key management.
- Have encrypted inboxes by default.
- Are outside Fourteen Eyes jurisdictions -- especially the US jurisdiction.
- Have desktop email compatibility with Mozilla Thunderbird.

If you know of any email providers like this, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately. we are not recommendation professionals. A simple search does this. But SCRYPTmail.com does provide the most of your needs (I also use it)

Comment: protonmail.com would also fill _most_ of the requisites